# How to update values from bytea to varchar in Greenplum?

Tags: type-conversion, greenplum

I need to convert hexa to values and need to update the values in a `varchar` field, I have tried:

```
select pg_catalog.decode(column,'hex')
```

The above code converted hexa to values but when I try to update a `varchar` field I am getting an error:

```
column is a character varying and expression of type Bytea,
```

Casting with `::text` also doesn't do it.

Comment: My downvote is for not declaring your database (Greenplum) in the question. Read the tag wiki of Postgres.

Answer (score 3):

To convert an hexadecimal string to characters, the encoding must be specified.
This is necessary because the same series of bytes may produce different characters depending on their encoding.

For instance, if the hex codes represent an `utf-8` string, use:

```
select convert_from(decode(your_hex_string, 'hex'), 'utf-8');
```

If the encoding is not supported by the built-in `convert_from()`, see [UTF16 hex to text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26607867)  for several alternative conversion techniques.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel , we are using Greenplum i coudn't find Convert_from function , Have any idea ?

Comment: @WilliamR: no. Does that product have an online manual?